# typeid().name(); wrong input

Tags: c++

I am trying to get the output hello with the variable type S for string or Ss. But I get some other long weird output. HelloNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int var1 = 40;
    float var2 = 79.569;
    string var3 = "Hello";
  
    cout << var1 << typeid(var1).name() << endl;
    cout << var2 << typeid(var2).name() << endl; 
    cout << var3 << typeid(var3).name() << endl; 
  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `string` is an alias for whatever the implementation actually calls it.  You can't expect any particular output in general.  What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 3):

> [`std::type_info::name`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name)
>
> Returns an **implementation defined** null-terminated character string
> containing the name of the type. No guarantees are given; in
> particular, the returned string can be identical for several types and
> change between invocations of the same program.

You can't rely on `name` on being anything in particular.

Comment: How would I be able to print the type for a string like the int and the float.

Comment: @Pygatti if you're using GCC, you could use [`abi::__cxa_demangle`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.3/a01696.html) to demangle the name returned by `std::type_info::name`, though that would give you `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>>`, which is the true name of `std::string`.  This is very implementation-defined though.

Comment: @Pygatti [your answer is probably in another castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), I'm afraid. If you expand on the problem that lead you to `typeinfo::name` as a potential solution in a new question (it's rude to change the question after it's been correctly answered) perhaps we can point you in a more satisfactory direction.

Comment: `char const* type_str(std::type_info const& t) { if (t == typeid(std::string)) return "string"; if (t == typeid(int)) return "int"; /*...*/ return "unknown"; }` and so forth for all the types you are interested in.